# add captch to registration modal box

Tags: users, javascript, captcha

I have a modal box for login and registration for my site.

[example.com](http://example.com/coupon)
I want to add the captcha with the registration process.I added the [captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) module in my site. But the captcha only work with the drupal's default registration page but not work with the modal box's registration.

How can I add the captcha with the modal box.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
$form['my_captcha_element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'captcha',
  '#captcha_type' => 'captcha/Math',
);
```

More info here :https://www.drupal.org/node/743056